# Encrypt the whole disk after installing 18.04

Tags: encryption

Windows or macOS provide easy ways to encrypt/decrypt the system drive (such as C:\ on Windows) whenever the user wants using GUI. It seems that the system drive encryption is an option at the installation GUI of Ubuntu, but there is no GUI to do it after installation, unlike Windows or macOS.

What if I want to encrypt it after installing Ubuntu normally? And what if I want to decrypt it after installation with the encryption option? Is that supported? I mean, without reinstalling the system.

There seem to be some tutorials about encrypting the home directory after installation, instead. So, on Ubuntu, it is recommended to encrypt only the home directory instead of the whole disk?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The popular operating systems make this easy. Its time that Ubuntu does as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant encrypt your system with veracrypt on ubuntu, just folders for secret files...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Veracrypt`, it's a simple tool really effective, well-known and descending from `TrueCrypt`, which was a really tool but depreciate for his complexity

You can try this tutorial : [Encrypt data in linux with veracrypt](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/encrypt-data-in-linux-with-veracrypt-an-alternative-to-truecrypt)

Comment: I have used Veracrypt on Windows. Does this mean that with the Ubuntu's native disk encryption, you cannot (easily) encrypt/decrypt the whole system disk after installation?